# Rename files using Powershell must include GetDate & Increment numbers

Tags: powershell

I am struggling to get this `Powershell` code to work below. I would like to rename files as per below.

06.09.2022_15.05. MYUSER 1

If there is multiple files in the folder then be able to increment
06.09.2022_15.05. MYUSER 1
06.09.2022_15.05. MYUSER 2
06.09.2022_15.05. MYUSER 3

below is the code i am using but it is not working (obviously)

```
 $GetUser = [Environment]::UserName
 $i = 1
 Get-ChildItem *.pdf | 
 rename-item -NewName {((get-date).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy_HH.mm.")+" "+," "+ $GetUser +,$_.Extension -f $i++ )}
```

This returns

06.09.2022.15.05. MYUSER

As you can see it doesn't have the incremented number at the end

Comment: Why would it? There are no placeholders for the value in the template (`$_.Extension`) you're providing to `-f`

Comment: if you don't mind helping me, what would need to be done for something like the above to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your current script: you're not providing an appropriate template string for the `-f` operator, and that the `Rename-Item` `-NewName` block will execute in its own local scope, meaning the original value of `$i` is never modified when you do `$i++` inside the `-NewName` scriptblock.

Use `ForEach-Object` to construct the new name ahead of time, then pass it to `Rename-Item`:

```
$username = [Environment]::UserName
$counter = 1
$timestamp = Get-Date -Format 'dd.MM.yyyy_HH.mm.'

Get-ChildItem *.pdf |ForEach-Object {
  $newName = "{0} {1} {2}{3}" -f $timestamp,$username,$counter++,$_.Extension

  $_ |Rename-Item -NewName $newName
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not to take away from [Mathias' helpful solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73623748/14903754), but to offer an alternative using a *reference* variable type:

```
 [ref]$i = 1
 $date = (Get-Date).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy_HH.mm.")
 Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.pdf' | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { "{0} {1} {2}{3}" -f $date, $env:USERNAME, $i.Value++, $_.Extension } -WhatIf
```

Same results, just using `[ref]` type to access the counter variable (`$i`) we're looking to increment; *same difference*.